# Java NumberFormatException error for input null

Tags: java, joptionpane, numberformatexception

When I run my code below:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String dataStr=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter");

        if (dataStr!= null){
            int data=Integer.parseInt(dataStr);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ok"+data);
        }
    }
}
```

The terminal shows the following errors when I input null:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:9)
```

I think after adding the condition `dataStr!=null` I should not have such error.
Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: you need to enter a valid integer into the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the String returned from: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter");`

Can be one of three things:

- `null` (if the dialog is cancelled)
- A valid int numeric String -- then your Integer.parseInt will work
- Or any other non-numeric String.

When you simply press enter without entering a String, the returned value is the empty String, `""`, and this falls into the 3rd category. The best way to solve your problem is to 1) either parse your String inside a try/catch block, thus catching all invalid inputs, or 2) force the user input only numeric data, such as by using a JSlider or JSpinner.

For example:

```
if (dataStr != null){

    try {
        int data=Integer.parseInt(dataStr);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ok"+data);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // notify user that input was invalid
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change condition from

`if (dataStr!= null){`

to

`if (dataStr!= null && (!dataStr.trim().isEmpty())){`

Comment: You're sure this is not an HTML Javascript problem?

Comment: It works. But why I cannot only use (dataStr!= null) ? Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Liass: you're not receiving a null value from the JOptionPane but rather an empty String, and you can't parse an empty String without throwing an exception. Myself, I would not recommend Raman's solution since it's too restrictive. I'd surround my parse with a try/catch NumberFormatException.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels   Well! I see! That helps a lot for me to understand! I would try the try/catch one. Thank you so much.